# Individual Background for "a" for each list element?

Tags: list, menu, background

I want to create a menu with diferent backgrounds for each list elements!

```
/* Adding some background color to the different menu items */

.nav li:nth-child(6n+1) {background: rgb(208, 101, 3); 
    background-image: url('noise.png');}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+2) {
    background: rgb(233, 147, 26);
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+3) {
    background: rgb(22, 145, 190);  
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+4) {
    background: rgb(22, 107, 162);  
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+5) {
    background: rgb(27, 54, 71);    
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background: rgb(21, 40, 54);
    background-image: url('noise.png');
}
```

This is the code for individual element background.
I want this code to change the background for each "a" element for the list not for the "li" element !

Comment: What are you expecting the `:nth-child(6n+x)` to do? Why not just have `:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2), etc.`?

Comment: @BryceHanscomb: To make them repeating, what else?

Comment: What's your problem, does `.nav li:nth-child(6n+x) a` not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style the `a` tag, you must specify that in your selector. At the moment, your CSS is giving backgrounds to the `li` element, because that's what it's searching for. You need to add `a` to the end of each one like so:

```
.nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a {
    background: rgb(208, 101, 3); 
    background-image: url('noise.png');}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a {
    background: rgb(233, 147, 26);
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a {
    background: rgb(22, 145, 190);  
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a {
    background: rgb(22, 107, 162);  
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a {
    background: rgb(27, 54, 71);    
    background-image: url('noise.png');

}

.nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a {
    background: rgb(21, 40, 54);
    background-image: url('noise.png');
}
```

This tells the engine to find the `a` in each `.nav li:nth-child()`. Be aware that you cannot make this code more efficient by changing the selector to `.nav li a:nth-child()` because there seems to be only one `a` per `li`, so the `nth-child` counter will never get past `1`.

However, I would recommend you abstract your background image declaration away into its own selector so you're not repeating yourself:

```
.nav li a {
    background-image: url('noise.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> change the background for each "a" element for the list not for the "li" element

Then select that, not the `li`!

```css
.nav li a { background-image: url('noise.png'); }
/*      ^  */
.nav li:nth-child(6n+1) a { background-color: rgb(208, 101, 3); }
.nav li:nth-child(6n+2) a { background-color: rgb(233, 147, 26); }
.nav li:nth-child(6n+3) a { background-color: rgb(22, 145, 190); }
.nav li:nth-child(6n+4) a { background-color: rgb(22, 107, 162); }
.nav li:nth-child(6n+5) a { background-color: rgb(27, 54, 71); }
.nav li:nth-child(6n+6) a { background-color: rgb(21, 40, 54); }
/*                      ^  */
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to create a fluid width menu with table, table row, and cells; to match the width of the site, no matter how many menu items I have.